# Let $T\colon V\to V$ over the IPS $V$ and $B$ be an orthogonal basis for $V$. Find the simplest connexion between $[T^*]_B$ and $([T]_B)^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

> Let $T\colon V\to V$ over an Inner Product Space $V$.
> Let $B$ be an orthogonal basis for $V$.
> Find the simplest connexion between
> $[T^*]_B$ and $([T]_B)^*$.

So I know that if $B$ was an orthonormal basis for $V$ we would have received:
$$[T^*]_B=\langle T^*{b_i},b_j\rangle=\operatorname{adj}\langle T{b_i},b_j\rangle=\operatorname{adj}([T]_B)_{ji}$$
and therefore $\,[T^*]_B=([T]_B)^*$.

I am not sure how to find this relation using $B$ as an orthogonal basis.
Do I just normalise the vectors?

Comment: Your notation is strange. What exactly is $\operatorname{adj} \langle T_{b_i},b_j\rangle $ supposed to mean?

Comment: Also, I would presume that $V$ is supposed to be finite-dimensional. If that's correct, you should say so explicitly.

Comment: @Angelo It seems that you changed $T^*bi$ to $T^*_{b_i}$. I think that the askers intent was $T^* b_i$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, look at the OP’s question. Is it right now? Could you tell me what does $T^*b_i$ mean ? Is it $T^*(b_i)$?

Comment: @Angelo Yes, $T^*b_i$ is the same as $T^*(b_i)$. In linear algebra, it is common to leave out the parentheses in the expression $T(x)$ for an operator $T$ and vector $x$

Comment: @Angelo and yes, it looks like the edits are at least consistent with OP's intent. I'm still not sure what $\operatorname{adj}\langle Tb_i,b_j\rangle$ is supposed to mean, though from the context I do have a guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A = \{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$ denote the orthonormal basis obtained by normalizing the orthogonal basis $B = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. Let $d_j = \|v_j\|$ for $j = 1,\dots,n$. Note that $v_j = d_j u_j$ for each $j = 1,\dots,n$.

The [change of basis matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) from $B$ to $A$ is the diagonal matrix
$$
P^B_A = \pmatrix{d_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && d_n}.
$$
We note that
\begin{align}
[T^*]_B &= (P^B_A)^{-1}[T^*]_A P^B_A = (P^B_A)^{-1}[T]_A^* P^B_A
\\ & = (P^B_A)^{-1}(P^B_A[T]_B (P^B_A)^{-1})^* P^B_A
\\ & = (P^B_A)^{-1}(P^B_A)^{-*}[T]_B^* (P^B_A)^*P^B_A
 = (P^B_A)^{-2} [T]_B^* (P^B_A)^2.
\end{align}
In other words, if $M$ denotes the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $M_{jj} = d_j^2 = \|v_j\|^2$, then
$$
[T^*]_B = M^{-1} [T]_B^* M.
$$

Comment: thank you so much your proof is super clear. I actually didn't even consider the idea of using a transition matrix!

Comment: @Asi You’re welcome! By the way, I’d appreciate it if you could “accept” this answer by clicking the checkmark (✔️) next to the vote arrows on my question.

Comment: Grossman of course! thank you very much